# Cuando abro un Modal en HTML se selecciona por defecto el boton de cerrar

Tags: bootstrap

estoy usando bootstrap para abrir un modal, pero cuando abro el modal se me selecciona por defecto el boton de cerrar, es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{ selectedFile.name }}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" style="height: 500px">
    <form>
      <iframe
        *ngIf="selectedFile.type === '0'"
        [src]="joinRoute(selectedFile.source)"
        style="height: 450px; width: 100%"
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allowfullscreen"
      ></iframe>
      <iframe
        *ngIf="selectedFile.type === '1'"
        width="100%"
        height="450"
        [src]="this.safeURL(selectedFile.source)"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen
        >Go to resource</iframe
      >
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ponle un atributo `tabindex="-1"` al botón

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el atributo `tabindex`. Esto indicará si el elemento será seleccionado o no (si es -1, no se va a seleccionar por defecto):

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{ selectedFile.name }}</h4>
    <button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" style="height: 500px">
    <form>
      <iframe
        *ngIf="selectedFile.type === '0'"
        [src]="joinRoute(selectedFile.source)"
        style="height: 450px; width: 100%"
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allowfullscreen"
      ></iframe>
      <iframe
        *ngIf="selectedFile.type === '1'"
        width="100%"
        height="450"
        [src]="this.safeURL(selectedFile.source)"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen
        >Go to resource</iframe
      >
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Genial, me funcionó super!, muchas gracias

Comment: Recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como "aceptada" para dejar la pregunta como respondida :)

Comment: Si, sino que tenia que esperar cierto tiempo jajaja, como fue tan rápido la respuesta, no me permitia aceptarla